# Android Renderscript examples force closing

Tags: android, renderscript, forceclose

I found this [link](http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCarousel) and I wanted to try the carousel example out. I copied all the classes and rs file (all that there was from the carousel example) into my own project and I tried building it on an actual device (Motorola xoom). But I keep getting force closes. The error in the logcat is:

```
11-01 11:37:23.490: E/RenderScript(927): 0x17c718, couldn't find an EGLConfig matching 
the screen format
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example/com.android.example.CarouselActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.renderscript.Allocation.elementFromBitmap(Allocation.java:821)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.renderscript.Allocation.typeFromBitmap(Allocation.java:839)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.renderscript.Allocation.createFromBitmap(Allocation.java:864)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.renderscript.Allocation.createFromBitmapResource(Allocation.java:1074)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselRS.loadImages(CarouselRS.java:127)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselRS.initRS(CarouselRS.java:188)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselRS.init(CarouselRS.java:36)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselView.ensureRenderScript(CarouselView.java:25)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselView.<init>(CarouselView.java:13)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
com.android.example.CarouselActivity.onCreate(CarouselActivity.java:15)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
11-01 12:09:53.320: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     ... 11 more
```

I don't know what this means and how I should fix this. Does anyone have this kind of problem?

Comment: Getting the same error on GoogleTV emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the post, I run it on actual device, not the emulator. the problem was this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21006), but they removed the problem in android sdk tools revision 15. So download the new version of sdk tools, and it should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about motorola xoom,it w . But usually i get compile time errors due to root method which has an argument . Remove the argument to "int root() {" and it should work.

One more thing : They dont work on emulators because emulator support is not yet there.

Comment: I know that the examples don't work on the emulator and I also removed the root method's argument. Sth else is the problem.. Thx for replying, I will keep trying to get this examples to work

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Renderscript wont work on emulator. Run the same on the device which has android 3.0 or later.